# Is it good practice to use odbcClose(channel) after loading the SQL Tables?

Tags: r, shiny, rodbc

Referencing the following example: [http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-shiny-example-sap-hana-r-and-shiny/](http://A%20Shiny%20Example%20w/%20RODBC%20at%20R-Bloggers)

In the following example, they run `odbcClose(ch)` after they get the tables they want.  Is it good practice to use `odbcClose(channel)` after you load the tables into your workspace?  Should anything different be done when using the SQL connection in a  `Shiny` app?

```
library("shiny")
library("RODBC")

ch<-odbcConnect("HANA_TK",uid="SYSTEM",pwd="manager")
odbcQuery(ch,"SELECT table_name from SYS.CS_TABLES_ where schema_name = 'SFLIGHT'")
tables<-sqlGetResults(ch)
**odbcClose(ch)**

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("SAP HANA and R using Shiny"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Table", "Choose a table:",
                choices = tables$TABLE_NAME),
    numericInput("Records", "Number of Records to view:", 10)
  ),

  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("view")
  )
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have yet to see any problems develop if I leave them open though.  I think R will eventually closed any unused connections.

I'm not sure if there is a system level benefit, but I have developed a habit of closing my channels as soon as possible.

When my system administrator needs to do certain tasks, he may need to shut down the server, and he tries to make it a point not to do that if someone is currently accessing the data.  An open connection appears to him as if someone is accessing the data, and so he waits until the connection is closed to turn off the server.  If I've left a stray open connection, he may never feel like he can do his maintenance.

So by anecdote of professional courtesy, I close my connections as soon as I can.